# UISegmentedControl setTint for UISegments only works after clicking

Tags: xcode, ios6, uisegmentedcontrol, uicolor, tint

Xcode, Obj-c, <s>iOS 5.2</s> iOS **6.0**

I have a UISegmentedControl which is being inserted into the bottom toolbar using something like this:

```
-(void) makeSegmentedControl {
    self.SegControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Title1",@"Title2"]];
    self.SegControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [self.SegControl setTarget:self action:@selector(handleSegment) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]
    [self.SegControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
 }
 -(void) AddSegmentedControlToToolbar {
     UIBarButtonItem *tmp = [UIBarButtonItem new];
     [tmp setCustomView:self.SegControl];
     [self.navigationController.toolbar setItems@[tmp]];
 }
 -(void) tintSegmentedControl {
     for (int i = 0; i< [self.SegControl.subviews count]; i++) {
          [[self.SegControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTint:[UIcolor greenColor];
      }
      NSArray * sortedViews = [self.SegControl.subviews sortArrayUsingFunction:sortFunction];
      [[sortedViews objectAtIndex:self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex] setTintColor:[UIColor lightGreenColor]];
      for (id view in self.SegControl.subviews) {
          [view removeFromSuperView];
      }
      for (id view in sortedViews) {
          [self.SegControl addSubview:view];
      }
 }
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
     [self makeSegmentedControl];
     [self addSegmentedControlToToobar];
     [self tintSegmentedControl];
  } 
  -(void) handleSegment {
      [self tintSegmentedControl];
  }
```

When I run the similar code in our app it shows a very BLUE UISegmentedController which turns GREEN on clicking. I've tried a few things and it seems that the tint on the UISegments just refuses to stick until after the view has finished loading. Any idea what's happening here?

### Edit

So, it turns out I was actually using the iOS 6.0 simulator and there is a restriction in iOS 6 that you can't tint a UISegmentedController before ViewDidAppear:Animated: has run. I think that this was the problem, because when I make this change:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     [self makeSegmentedControl];
     [self addSegmentedControlToToobar];
} 
-(void)viewDidAppear {
     [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(tintSegmentedControl) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

it works. Not 100% sure what's going on. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out there is a restriction in iOS 6 that you can't tint a UISegmentedController before ViewDidAppear:Animated: has run. To circumvent it I made this code change (as you can see in the edit).

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     [self makeSegmentedControl];
     [self addSegmentedControlToToobar];
} 
-(void)viewDidAppear {
     [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(tintSegmentedControl) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
-(void) tintSegmentedControl {
    [self.SegControl setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor];
      NSArray * sortedViews = [self.SegControl.subviews sortArrayUsingFunction:sortFunction];
      [[sortedViews objectAtIndex:self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex] setTintColor:[UIColor lightGreenColor]];
      for (id view in self.SegControl.subviews) {
          [view removeFromSuperView];
      }
      for (id view in sortedViews) {
          [self.SegControl addSubview:view];
      }
 }
```

Comment: Already tried that, actually. The setTintColor for SegControl works, but the selected segment still doesn't get highlighted.